# What CSS do I do to make this button (look below)?

Tags: html, css

**This is what I want to create**
[image: The image I want my button to look like]

**Some of My HTML code**

```html
<div class="account">
   <ul>
     <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

**This is some of my CSS, but its not working:**

```css
.account ul li {
  float            : right;
  list-style       : none;
  padding-right    : 20px;
  margin-top       : 5px;
  margin-bottom    : 5px;
  border-width     : 5px;
  border-color     : #fcbf49;
  background-color : white;
  }
.account ul li a {
  text-decoration : none;
  font-family     : 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-size       : 30px;
  color           : #fcbf49;
}
```

Comment: i dont get it, you are talking about a `button` and your code uses a `link`!
why not just use a `<button>`? and why did you add in your example some                               `<ul>` `<li>` `<divs>`... what is the interest in this question?

Comment: Please start with `<button type="button">Profile</button>` instead of `<a href="#">Profile</a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.account ul li {
  max-width: max-content;
  list-style       : none;
  padding-right    : 20px;
  margin-top       : 5px;
  margin-bottom    : 5px;
  /* border-width     : 5px; */
  border: 7px solid #fcbf49;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  /* border-color     : #fcbf49; */
  background-color : white;
  }
.account ul li a {
  text-decoration : none;
  font-family     : 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-size       : 30px;
  color           : #fcbf49;
}
```

```html
<div class="account">
   <ul>
     <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Rounin it was just because the question uses an anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn {  
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  border: 5px solid #fcbf49;  
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fcbf49;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Profile</button>
```

And i see you need it for list. I think for a navbar then use this:

```css
.btn {  
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  border: 5px solid #fcbf49;  
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fcbf49;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="account">
   <ul>
     <li> <a class="btn" href="#">Profile</a> </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go .

```css
.account ul li {
   list-style       : none;
  padding:1rem;
}

.account ul li a {
   text-decoration       : none;
   color           : #fcbf49;
  font-weight: bolder;
   font-family     : 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-size:2rem;
  border: 4px solid #fcbf49;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="account">
   <ul>
     <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
   </ul>
 </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main mistake was not setting a border-style. I'm sure you van figure out the rest yourself ;).

```css
.account ul li {
  float            : right;
  list-style       : none;
  padding-right    : 20px;
  margin-top       : 5px;
  margin-bottom    : 5px;
  border-width     : 5px;
  border-style     : solid; /* you forgot this */
  border-color     : #fcbf49;
  background-color : white;
  }
.account ul li a {
  text-decoration : none;
  font-family     : 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-size       : 30px;
  color           : #fcbf49;
}
```

```html
<div class="account">
   <ul>
     <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<a href="#"><button class="button button1">Profile</button></a>
```

**css**

```
 .button
{
  background-color: #FFFF00; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white; 
  color: #ff8c00; 
  border: 5px solid #ff8c00;
  }
```

**demo**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There were a few little problems with the given code.

The main one is that the border was not given a style solid so it didn't pick up the other border styling.

The other main point is that the word is required to be central within the borderso the padding needs to be symmetric left and right and also symmetric top and bottom.

One other observation - I suspect you require the whole list to be on the right hand side so this snippet sets this as float right. However, it may be useful to look at other ways of doing this such as positioning right or maybe the whole navbar could be set with flex - some items to the left some central - some to the right.

```css
.account ul {
  float: right;
}

.account ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.account ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fcbf49;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #fcbf49;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="account">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Profile</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```